Second derivative of unit vector
We know that the second derivative of unit vector (the vector from a point toward the source) is proportional to the Electric field caused by the source in a particular point.
If we imagine that our source is a charge that oscillates in small amplitude , and the distance between source and observer is so far in comparation to amplitude. We can say that distance doesn't change during the motion of charge. So we can compute the transverse components of the motion ( by considering that our line of sight is perpendicular to these components, and applying some geometry) :
\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\hat{e}_x&=\frac{1}{R}\,\frac{d^2x'}{dt^2},\notag\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\hat{e}_y&=\frac{1}{R}\,\frac{d^2y'}{dt^2},
\end{align}
So second derivative of unit vector is proportional to acceleration of charge only if $R$ is constant and these formulas are valid only if $R$ is constant, But $R$ always changes during the motion of charge.
But i want to know that why each component of second derivative of unit vectors is  always proportional to the same component of acceleration?
Whenever $R$ changes how we conclude that acceleration is proportional to the second derivative of unit vector?

Sorry for the multiple edits, previously I wrote a more general section on unit vectors. I'm not happy with it, after more careful thought. This is the part I am ok with and will leave here for your reference:
I can refer you to the Feynman lectures - Chapter 28 - Volume I - Electromagnetic Radiation. I'll try to quote the relevant parts here:

As the charge moves around, the unit vector wiggles, and the acceleration of that unit vector is what we are looking for. That is all. Thus $$\mathbf{E}=−\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0 c^2}\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 \mathbf{e'}_r}{\mathrm{d}t^2}$$ is a statement of the laws of radiation, because that is the only important term when we get far enough away that the fields are varying inversely as the distance.

I'm assuming that is the starting point of your query. Then he goes on to explain

The unit vector $\boldsymbol{e'}_r$ is pointed toward the apparent position of the charge. Of course, the end of $\boldsymbol{e'}_r$ goes on a slight curve, so that its acceleration has two components. One is the transverse piece, because the end of it goes up and down, and the other is a radial piece because it stays on a sphere. It is easy to demonstrate that the latter is much smaller and varies as the inverse square of $r$ when $r$ is very great. This is easy to see, for when we imagine that we move a given source farther and farther away, then the wigglings of $\boldsymbol{e'}_r$ look smaller and smaller, inversely as the distance, but the radial component of acceleration is varying much more rapidly than inversely as the distance. So for practical purposes all we have to do is project the motion on a plane at unit distance.

Feynman goes on to also say:

If the charged object is moving in a very small motion and it is laterally displaced by the distance $x(t)$, then the angle that the unit vector $\mathbf{e'}_r$ is displaced is $x/r$, and since $r$ is practically constant, the $x$-component of $\mathrm{d}^2\mathbf{e'}_r/\mathrm{d}t^2$ is simply the acceleration of $x$ itself at an earlier time divided by $r$, and so finally we get the law we want, which is
$$E_x(t)=−\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0c^2 r}a_x\left(t−\frac{r}{c}\right).$$ Only the component $a_x$, perpendicular to the line of sight, is important. Let us see why that is. Evidently, if the charge is moving in and out straight at us, the unit vector in that direction does not wiggle at all, and it has no acceleration. So it is only the sidewise motion which is important, only the acceleration that we see projected on the screen.

Hope this helps.

I conclude that the end of unit vector doesn't go on a plate or line as the charge moves _ except for the one dimensional motion along the line of sight _ and it goes on a curve even if the motion of charge is in a line or a plate _ R will definitely change during the motion_, so acceleration of unit vector is proportional to acceleration of charge because R is regarded to be constant. Is it?

@Rojan Yes, the main point is that when the charge is far away compared to the amplitude of its oscillation, the unit vector "wiggles" along a curve but the curve is so small that it is approximately a straight line projected a unit distance from the tail of the vector. Btw, see additional discussion of this explanation by Feynman in these posts: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70039/help-me-understand-eqn-28-6-from-feynman , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/375191/is-feynman-correct-about-this-inverse-square-relationship-in-vol-i-28
